# Problem with Baking Dynamic Paint with Ocean modifier

Tags: baking, dynamic-paint, cache, ocean-simulation

I've got problem with baking Dynamic paint which I use to make wave from Brush object and foam trail from it. And I use Ocean modifier
[image: viewport without baking]

This is how it looks in viewport without baking, it should look similar in render

[image: baked ocean modifier]

When I bake Ocean modifier foam spreads everywhere

[image: baked dynamic paint]

But when I bake dynamic paint everything (waves from ocean modifier and foam trail) looks good, except it doesn't have waves from brush object (sphere)

Maybe, I making some dumb mistake, but I can`t find reason

Answer (score 0):

press bake all dynamics and save file.

Comment: doesn`t solve problem

Comment: ok, then please provide blend file

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/76QQTE_C4iPmxQ

Comment: bad link/permissions

Comment: First thoughts: apply transforms like scale where you can. Make sure the origin of the objects is in their geometric center (origin to geometry)